# Laravel - How to update table multiple rows at once

Tags: laravel

I have this variable called `$projectFieldOptions` and it's output is like this:

https://prnt.sc/7HtxrfTy9HiI.

Now, In the Controller I need to update this. What I am doing this, first **delete** all the existing rows based on `id_feed` and `id_project` and then loop through this variable `$projectFieldOptions` and insert it. Like this:

```
if( $request->feed_type !== 'scrape' ) { 
    $delete_mapping = DB::connection($db_name)->table($db_name . '.feed_mappings')
    ->where('id_feed', '=', $id_feed)
        ->where('id_project', '=', $token)
        ->delete();
}

// now insert 
$field_mapping = true;
if( $request->feed_type !== 'scrape' ) { 
    if( count($projectFieldOptions) ) {
        foreach ($projectFieldOptions as $mapping) {
            $data[] = [
                'id_feed'       => $id_feed,
                'id_project'    => $token,
                'import_field_slug' => $mapping['value'],
                'internal_field_slug' => $mapping['custom'] ? $mapping['custom_field'] : $mapping['text'],
                'custom_field'  => $mapping['custom'],
                'updates'   =>  $mapping['updates'],
                'removes'   =>  $mapping['removes'],
                'import'        => 1,
                'date_add'      => now(),
                'date_upd'      => now()
            ];
        }
    } else {
        $data = [];
    } 

    $field_mapping = DB::connection($db_name)->table($db_name . ".feed_mappings")->insert($data);
}
```

Now, I don't want to delete existing rows instead I want to update those rows based on the `id_feed_mappings`. Can you tell how can I do this?

Comment: does [`upserts` function](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#upserts) didn't cater your needs?

Comment: @BagusTesa let me try with this.

Comment: @BagusTesa How can I set the `where` condtion in this `upserts` function? I need to update those rows based ond `id_feed_mappings` value.

Answer (score 0):

> Check if this would work, to update based on `id_feed_mappings` value, you can use the `->where('id_feed_mappings', '=' ,'a value or variable')` before `->update($data)`

```
if( $request->feed_type !== 'scrape' ) { 

// try using update instead of insert

 
$field_mapping = true;
if( $request->feed_type !== 'scrape' ) { 
    if( count($projectFieldOptions) ) {
        foreach ($projectFieldOptions as $mapping) {
            $data[] = [
                'id_feed'       => $id_feed,
                'id_project'    => $token,
                'import_field_slug' => $mapping['value'],
                'internal_field_slug' => $mapping['custom'] ? $mapping['custom_field'] : $mapping['text'],
                'custom_field'  => $mapping['custom'],
                'updates'   =>  $mapping['updates'],
                'removes'   =>  $mapping['removes'],
                'import'        => 1,
                'date_add'      => now(),
                'date_upd'      => now()
            ];
        }
    } else {
        $data = [];
    } 

    $field_mapping = DB::connection($db_name)->table($db_name . ".feed_mappings")->update($data);
}
```